# Entity Framework many to many on the same table without duplicite records

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am trying to implement communication between user1 and user2. User1 can communicate with many users, also user2 can communicate with many users.

I am trying to avoid having duplicate rows in intersect table (Chat).

Example: user1 chatting with User2 is the same record as user2 chatting with user1. There should be just one record of their communication in Chat table.

What is the best approach to solve this situation?

I was thinking about making one to many relationship between user and chat entity with composite key of both users.

I have two classes User.cs and Chats.cs.

```
public class User
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Chat> Chats { get; set; }
}

public class Chat
{
    public User User { get; set; }
    public long UserId1 { get; set; }
    public long UserId2 { get; set; } 
}
```

//chatconfigure

```
public static void Configure(EntityTypeConfiguration<Chat> entity)
{
    entity.HasKey(c => new { c.UserId1, c.UserId2 });
    entity.HasRequired(s => s.User)
          .WithMany(d => d.Chats)
          .HasForeignKey(s => new { s.UserId1, s.UserId2 });
}
```

Error:

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> Chat_User_Source: Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'Chat_User_Source' in relationship 'Chat_User'. Because the Dependent Role refers to the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '1'.
>   Chat_User_Target_Chat_User_Source: : The number of properties in the Dependent and Principal Roles in a relationship constraint must be identical.

Comment: Don't think is possible or correct to say that `User1` -> `User2` is the same as `User2` -> `User1`. Maybe if you need to be the same you should implement a `ChatActive` table with 2 properties `UserId` and `ChatId`.

Comment: You can add constraint: `ALTER TABLE Chat ADD CHECK (UserId1 > UserId2 );`